# How to find if a specific tab is empty using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to find if a specific tab is empty or not. I found some examples on SO but they all go through loops, which is not the case here. I tried to figure out how to modify those examples to apply to my specific case, but couldn't. In the code below, I can only retrieve the tab caption, but how to get the content inside it?

```
<li> <a href="#" onclick="SelectMainTab('#tabABC')">A B C</a></li>
<li> <a href="#" onclick="SelectMainTab('#tab123')">1 2 3</a></li>

function SelectMainTab(_tabName) {
    // Select the tab  THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED
    $('#tabMain a[href="' + _tabName + '"]').tab("show");

    // This returns the tab caption, but what I need is the tab content
    var temp = $('#tabMain a[href="' + _tabName + '"]').html().trim();

    // Once the above works, I will write code here to check if it is empty or not

    return false;
}
```

Comment: For the one who down voted: Do you have a solution to the question? Do you know how to retrieve the html from inside the tab using the code above?

Comment: Check my answer and updates. I didn't vote your question down.

Comment: I don't know why the down vote, maybe passing the params in jquery or using the onclick event. I'm all for clean and efficient code, but what some newbies don't understand is that in the end, everything compiles downs to the assembly language for the cpu to process it.

Comment: I got 5 downvotes in a question today, marked as off-topic when it's absolutely not. So, chill. If someone doesn't like the question, s/he downvotes it here. Doesn't need to have a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li> <a href="#" class="tabSelector">A B C</a></li>
<li> <a href="#" class="tabSelector">1 2 3</a></li>

$('.tabSelector').on('click', function(){


  var $myDivContent = $(this).html(); 

  if($.trim($myDivContent).length === 0){

      // tab is empty
   }

});
```

Don't use `onClick` function since it's a bad practice. Use `.on()` instead. Check if it's working now.

And you don't need to pass `tabname` like that. Javascript creates `this` variable in every execution context. You can set `rel` instead and get the value of it like that:

```
<li> <a href="#" rel="tab1" class="tabSelector">A B C</a></li>
var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
```

Comment: This is a code only answer, and the code doesn't work. You have your opening parenthesis for the if statement in the wrong place, a missing `$` before `(this)`, and there is no `.trim()` method in jQuery that can be applied to a jQuery collection, only the `$.trim()` function

Comment: You should be using `.on()` instead of `.bind()` from jQuery 1.7 too.

Comment: `.bind()` also works, i think. I first used `.on()` though

Comment: It works, but it has been superseded by `.on()` and in all likelihood will be deprecated as newer versions of jQuery are released.

Comment: @Andy Thanks. I didn't realize those mistakes at first and went on to do some nodejs stuff after posting it. Then came back and saw. :p

Comment: @Andy For some reason the script wasn't been reached. I had to change it to  $(document).on("click", ".tabSelector", function (e) {}.... and then, finally everything worked. Thanks for the answer and also for the tips on  using 'rel'. Very useful